# How to get entity coordinates that are located inside an OSM administrative boundary?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, st-intersects

I downloaded the administrative boundary of Germany from a [website](https://osm-boundaries.com/) as `*.geojson` file.

I imported this `*.geojson` file into PostgreSQL like this.

```
./apps/ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=<host> port=<port> dbname=<db> user=<user> password=<secret>" "<*.geojson file>"
```

The boundary in PostgreSQL looks like this.

```
\d public.osmb_f34bb1e807df3ba4a0f046517b854c9b73a914f1
                                            Table "public.osmb_f34bb1e807df3ba4a0f046517b854c9b73a914f1"
    Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                                    Default                                     
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ogc_fid      | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('osmb_f34bb1e807df3ba4a0f046517b854c9b73a914f1_ogc_fid_seq'::regclass)
 osm_id       | integer                     |           |          | 
 boundary     | character varying           |           |          | 
 admin_level  | integer                     |           |          | 
 parents      | character varying           |           |          | 
 name         | character varying           |           |          | 
 local_name   | character varying           |           |          | 
 name_en      | character varying           |           |          | 
 wkb_geometry | geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "osmb_f34bb1e807df3ba4a0f046517b854c9b73a914f1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ogc_fid)
    "osmb_f34bb1e807df3ba4a0f046517b854c9b73a9_wkb_geometry_geom_idx" gist (wkb_geometry)
```

It is the boundary of Germany.

```
sib00_delfi=> select osm_id,boundary,admin_level,parents,name,local_name,name_en from osmb_f34bb1e807df3ba4a0f046517b854c9b73a914f1 limit 3;
 osm_id |    boundary    | admin_level | parents |  name   | local_name  | name_en 
--------+----------------+-------------+---------+---------+-------------+---------
 -51477 | administrative |           2 |         | Germany | Deutschland | Germany
(1 row)
```

I have a table of entries with geo coordinates of type `geometry(Point,4326)` that looks like this

```
                              Table "gtfs.stops"
        Column         |         Type         | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------------+----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 feed_index            | integer              |           | not null | 
 stop_id               | text                 |           | not null | 
 stop_name             | text                 |           |          | 
...
 stop_lat              | double precision     |           |          | 
 stop_lon              | double precision     |           |          | 
...
 the_geom              | geometry(Point,4326) |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "stops_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (feed_index, stop_id)
    "stop_geom_idx" gist (the_geom)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "stops_feed_index_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (feed_index) REFERENCES gtfs.feed_info(feed_index) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "stops_level_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (feed_index, level_id) REFERENCES
...
Referenced by:
...
Triggers:
    stop_geom_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON gtfs.stops FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE gtfs.stop_geom_update()
```

and holds the following number of entries.

```
select count(stop_id) FROM gtfs.stops;
 count  
--------
 523887
```

I was wondering how many entries are located inside the above mentioned boundary and called this query.

```
select count(stop_id) FROM gtfs.stops LEFT JOIN public.osmb_f34bb1e807df3ba4a0f046517b854c9b73a914f1 AS de ON ST_Intersects(gtfs.stops.the_geom, de.wkb_geometry);
 count  
--------
 523887
```

I know from this [page](https://www.delfi.swingbe.de/) that many entities are located outside of that boundary.

So, I am wondering why my query states, that all entries are located inside that boundary. Any ideas on this? Cheers!

Comment: **left** join keeps every record. Try with a regular join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for opening my eyes to the inner join with `JOIN` instead of the outer join with `LEFT JOIN`. That solved my confusion.

I got all entities inside the OSM boundary like this.

> CREATE TABLE analysis.tbl_stops_de AS SELECT stop_id,stop_name,stop_desc,stop_lat,stop_lon,parent_station,location_type,level_id,platform_code FROM gtfs.stops JOIN public.de_al2_w_kiss1 AS de ON ST_Intersects(gtfs.stops.the_geom, de.wkb_geometry) order by stop_id, stop_name;

This way I got rid of about 10 percent of entities that are located outside.